# I get back wrong chars from bluetooth module (uart)

Tags: microcontroller, atmega, communication, bluetooth, uart

I would like to communicate between my atmega8 controller and PC via an HC-06 bluetooth module.

I should get back the same char that I send but I get some wrong characters.
The bluetooth module uses a 9600 baudrate (default), so I set my controller internal clock to 8Mhz. ( I don't know if I set correctly..)

```
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

#define F_CPU 8000000UL 

void USARTInit(uint16_t ubrr_value)
{
    //Set Baud rate
  UBRRL = ubrr_value;
  UBRRH = (ubrr_value>>8);

   /*Set Frame Format 
   >> Asynchronous mode
   >> No Parity
   >> 1 StopBit
   >> char size 8
   */
   UCSRC=(1<<URSEL)|(3<<UCSZ0);

   //Enable The receiver and transmitter
   UCSRB=(1<<RXEN)|(1<<TXEN);
}

void USARTWriteChar(char data)
{
    //Wait until the transmitter is ready
    while(!(UCSRA & (1<<UDRE)))
    {
        //Do nothing
    }

    //Now write the data to USART buffer
    UDR=data;
}

char USARTReadChar()
{
    //Wait untill a data is available
    while(!(UCSRA & (1<<RXC)))
    {
        //Do nothing
    }

    //Now USART has got data from host
    //and is available is buffer
    return UDR;
}

int main()
{      
   char data;
   USARTInit(51);    //UBRR = 51

   //Loop forever
   while(1)
   {
      //Read data
      data=USARTReadChar();

      /* Now send the same data but but surround it in
      square bracket. For example if user sent 'a' our
      system will echo back '[a]'.
      */

      USARTWriteChar('[');
      USARTWriteChar(data);
      USARTWriteChar(']');
   } 
   return 0;
}
```

I set the SUT_CKSEL to INTRCOSC_8MHZ_6CK_0MS at Fuses in Atmel studio to apply 8Mhz clock freq.

Test:

If I send 'k' then I get back [B],
If I send 'j' then I get back [@],
If I send 'h' then I get back [@],
If I send 'g' then I get back [F]... etc.

Comment: Do you have an RS-232 to TTL converter between the PC and the module?

Comment: No. Why would I need that? After I pair my pc and the module via bluetooth, I send the characters from  putty. This is the module: [link](http://www.ebay.com/itm/Wireless-Serial-4-Pin-Bluetooth-RF-Transceiver-Module-with-Backplane-RS232-New-/170787509360?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_15&hash=item27c3ba9470http://www.ebay.com/itm/Wireless-Serial-4-Pin-Bluetooth-RF-Transceiver-Module-with-Backplane-RS232-New-/170787509360?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_15&hash=item27c3ba9470)

Comment: The PC is the Bluetooth end, then. Sorry, that wasn't clear (to me, anyway).

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear enough :)

Comment: If I send const chars from controller to PC then everything is ok. The problem occurs when I send chars from PC, the controller doesn't get the right character. Any idea?

Comment: Strange that it works in one direction. Maybe check the configuration.. stop bit, start bit, parity to make sure they're right (and the same definitions are used).

Comment: I have tested the module with an arduino and works fine. I also set up an extern crystal (8MHz) for my atmega8 but I still don't get correct characters.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has been **abandoned in unanswerable condition for FOUR YEARS**.

Comment: Have you checked your code at a lower level (example: doing a one-byte serial port write operation in assembly)? Maybe your compiler has bugs and is converting your code into incorrect opcodes for the micro?

Answer (score 1):

This really sounds as a baud rate error. You have to be sure that your baudrate is set correctly. Can't you use your bluetoothmodule as a mirror to reflect incoming data straight back to your PC?

Comment: I should connect the Rx pin to the Tx directly?

Comment: nvm, i see that you are already mirroring data back.